Comic about a teenager and a telepathic lioness
I'd really like some help finding a comic I haven't read since I was in school. I would have read it in 2001-2002, though it may been released before then. I've tried googling it with no luck.
I swear it was called 'F.R.E.A.K' or something. The front cover had a teenager jumping in the air clutching/firing lightning from his hands. There were two issues I think, one with a blue background cover and one with a green background.
It was about some teenager who stumbles into an alternate dimension and meets a bipedal lion woman who can talk. There were other animal people, and they were at war.
The lions were police, and some of the characters had psychic powers and they were referred to as 'TK's'. The main bad guys were a vulture woman and a fat guy with angel wings, who all use guns. There were also lizard people and monkey people.
It was partially comic and partially written story. I remember it being very violent and adult orientated. Please, does anyone know what it is? Any help would be most appreciated.

Through the Lightning Gate and Death and the lizard man from Jim Eldridge, Stephen Player (Freak series)
From Goodreads:

Meet Freddy A. Kennedy - alias Freak. He's seventeen and pretty cool with it - but nothing could have prepared him for being zapped through the lighting gate... into a world where tribes of lizard-creatures and snarling dog-people prowl the streets night and day.


Enter Eon, the lion woman. She's the only one Freak meets who doesn't try to tear him limb from limb - she even helps him understand what's going on. So when Eon disappears, captured by the evil warlord Angel, Freak plans a rescue mission.

Covers:
 

Yes! That was the comic! Thank you sooooooo much! You're a life saver.
